# ESRI JavaScript HeatmapRenderer class and Print widget

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, printing, heat-map

I’m working on an application using ESRI’s [HeatMapRenderer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/heatmaprenderer-amd.html) class from the JavaScript API.  The issue that I am running into is that the Print widget fails if the heat map renderer layer is on the map. If I do not have the heat map layer on the map the Print widget works as expected.  I was wondering if anyone else has run into this issue, and if so what sort of solution was found.

Comment: Can you share the section of code which contains the layer (with heatmap) and the print widget?

Answer (score -1):

Please find below link for the same. Here they faced the same issue.

https://geonet.esri.com/thread/118346